# Splitting of a finite group with no abelian subfactor in composition series

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with no abelian subfactor in its composition series.

Is $G$ obtained from simple groups by iterating semidirect products?

(Initially it was asked whether $G$ is a direct product of simple groups, but $A_5\wr A_5$ was mentioned as an immediate counterexample.)

Comment: No. For example $G=A_5\wr A_5$ (wreath product).

Comment: @JoachimKönig this is indeed the smallest counterexample, in the sense that every finite group with $\le 5$ Jordan-Hölder subquotients, all non-abelian, is a direct product of simple groups.

Comment: I should mentioned that $G$ is not a product (direct, semi direct, wreath product etc.) of non abelian simple group

Comment: You need to make the question more precise. What exactly does "etc" mean? I predict that whatever definition of product you come up with, the answer to the question will be no.

Comment: It is trivially true that every (non-trivial) group has a (non-trivial) solvable subgroup - you don't need to use the non-trivial result of Suzuki to prove that!

Comment: Yes, it is now clear to me. Thank you, @DerekHolt

Comment: There's a reasonable question of finding a finite group with no abelian Jordan-Hölder factor, which is not obtained from simple groups by iterating semidirect products (and hence wreath as well, since wreath product is obtained from semidirect products). I think I heard of a quite elaborate example by Joseph Ayoub.

Comment: @YCor: I would be curious if an example is written down somewhere? If $X$ and $Y$ are non-abelian finite simple groups, by Schreier conjecture (outer automorphism groups solvable) every extension $1 \rightarrow X \rightarrow G \rightarrow Y \rightarrow 1$ is split. That would make me naively guess that every finite group with non-abelian Jordan-Hölder factors is constructed by iterated semidirect products, but seems that is wrong.

Comment: OK I will answer the more precise version of the question as formulated by YCor and spin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are groups that look like wreath products, but where the base group has no complement, so they are not semidirect products. The theory is described in an old paper of mine (and probably elsewhere):

D. F. Holt, Embeddings of group extensions into Wreath products, Quar. J. Math. (Oxford) 29 (1978), 463--468.

It can be seen as a non-abelian analogue of Shapiro's lemma in cohomology.

Roughly speaking, let $D$ be a group extension of $N$ by $H$ (meaning $N$ is the normal subgroup), suppose that the group $G$ contains $H$ as a subgroup, and let $\Omega$ be the set of (right or left) cosets of $H$ in $G$ with the transitive (right or left) action of $G$ on $\Omega$.

Then there is corresponding wreath product like extension $E$ of $N^\Omega$ by $G$, where the factors of $N^\Omega$ are permuted under conjugation corresponding to the action of $G$ on $\Omega$, and the normalizer in $E$ of a factor of the base group modulo the other factors of the base group is naturally isomorphic to $D$.

Furthermore, the extension $E$ is non-split if and only if $D$ is.

So, for example, we could take $D = {\rm Aut}(A_6)$ (as in spin's answer) with $N = {\rm Inn}(A_6) \cong A_6$, and $H = C_2^2$, and $G = A_5$, so $|\Omega| = 15$. This results in a non-split extension of $A_6^{15}$ by $A_5$, which cannot be constructed from simple groups by taking iterated semidirect products.

Comment: In my comment my vague intuition came from extensions of modules, where you know that if $V$ is a $K[G]$-module for a group $G$ and $\operatorname{Ext}^1(W,Z) = 0$ for all composition factors $W,Z$ of $V$, then $V$ is completely reducible. But as this answer shows that kind of stuff doesn't work for extensions of groups.

Answer (score 3):

The group $\operatorname{Aut}(A_6)$ has a unique simple normal subgroup, $\operatorname{Inn}(A_6) = A_6$. It is a nonsplit extension $$1 \rightarrow A_6 \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(A_6) \rightarrow C_2 \times C_2 \rightarrow 1.$$